# Scroll to anchor JS not working

Tags: javascript, html

So what I try to achieve is as the title says. I've gone through quite many threads and websites so far, but just can not get it working.

I can somehow see different scripts working when they have the time it takes to scroll editable. It just doesn't scroll smoothly, it jumps to the anchor after that time.

What I am currently using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hashTagActive = "";
    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        if(hashTagActive != this.hash) { //this will prevent if the user click several times the same link to freeze the scroll.
            event.preventDefault();
            //calculate destination place
            var dest = 0;
            if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            } else {
                dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            }
            //go to destination
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: dest
            }, 2000, 'swing', function(){
                hashTagActive = "";
            });
            hashTagActive = this.hash;
        }
    });
});
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Tervetuloa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Sivupohjia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Tilaa sivut</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#4">Linkki</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#5">Linkki</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#6">Linkki</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#7">Linkki</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#8">Linkki</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#9">Linkki</a></li>
        <li><a href="etusivu.html#10">Linkki</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content_primary">
            <a name="1" id="1"></a>
            <h3>Tervetuloa</h3>
            <p>Tekstiä</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content_secondary">
            <a name="2" id="2"></a>
            <h3>Sivupohjia</h3>
            <p>Tulossa</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content_primary">
            <a name="3" id="3"></a>
            <h3>Tilaa</h3>
            <p>Tekstiä</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy;&nbsp;Marko&nbsp;Ahola</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I simply have no idea where to go from here. I have no experience in this, I'm just a hobbyist. Any help is appreciated.

I have the website running on a Raspberry PI and Apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add your class name `scroll` to your first three anchor tags that you want smooth scrolling

```
  <li><a href="#1" class="scroll">Tervetuloa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" class="scroll">Sivupohjia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" class="scroll">Tilaa sivut</a></li>
```

Snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var hashTagActive = "";
      $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
        if (hashTagActive != this.hash) { //this will prevent if the user click several times the same link to freeze the scroll.
          event.preventDefault();
          //calculate destination place
          var dest = 0;
          if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
          } else {
            dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
          }
          //go to destination
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: dest
          }, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            hashTagActive = "";
          });
          hashTagActive = this.hash;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#1" class="scroll">Tervetuloa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2" class="scroll">Sivupohjia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3" class="scroll">Tilaa sivut</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#4">Linkki</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#5">Linkki</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#6">Linkki</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#7">Linkki</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#8">Linkki</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#9">Linkki</a></li>
      <li><a href="etusivu.html#10">Linkki</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content_primary">
        <a name="1" id="1"></a>
        <h3>Tervetuloa</h3>
        <p>Tekstiä</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content_secondary">
        <a name="2" id="2"></a>
        <h3>Sivupohjia</h3>
        <p>Tulossa</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content_primary">
        <a name="3" id="3"></a>
        <h3>Tilaa</h3>
        <p>Tekstiä</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>&copy;&nbsp;Marko&nbsp;Ahola</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I can now see it working on your snippet but when I try it locally or on the web server, it does not work. So am I missing a module or something on my RB Pi? My website can be found here: https://www.marko-ahola.com

Comment: Yes! Jquery script ! add  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Seems like that fixed the problem with the script not functioning. Thank you. Now there just must be something wrong with the page structure, or something, because it kind of works when testing on phone, but not on computer. I can see it scrolling slowly when testing on phone. Just doesn't go all the way to the anchor there either. On computer I still can't get it to work. Have to double click on the links to get it to the correct anchor. Anyways this solved the original problem, I'll try to fix the rest somehow. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh ok, little update. I got it to work. I used overflow-y: scroll on the container, but now I removed it and added position: fixed to navbar and footer. Works like a charm now. Thank you repzero one more time! For a newbie like me this made my hair turn gray.

Comment: feel free to accept answer if meet your requirements :D :D